# Is there any difference (index selection? speed?) in find_in_set vs or

Tags: mysql, sql, find-in-set

Is there any difference (index selection? speed?) between:

```
select * from table where x = 'a' or x = 'b'
```

vs

```
select * from table where find_in_set(x, 'a,b')
```

Should I use one of those or are they equal?

Comment: Try it? Look at the explain? Personally I would guess that the `OR` is faster since it's a standard operation and doesn't involve a function, but I rarely understand the reasoning of the MySQL query planner.

Comment: `but I rarely understand the reasoning of the MySQL query planner`- that is why I am asking the pros!

Answer (score 1):

`FIND_IN_SET` is a function call which should skip the index altogether.

You should consider using

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE x IN ('a', 'b')
```

instead.

Comment: IN's downside is it doesn't play well with prepared statements. Select * From table Where id IN(?) won't work. Select * From table Where FIND_IN_SET(id,?) will.

Comment: True! But you could possibly write an extension of the library to handle that case too.

Answer (score 1):

you should avoid 
    FIND_IN_SET 
when ever possible! 
In most cases it is used when columns are not normalized (e.g. csv in a cell). IN is very much faster since it's able to use indexes (if index exists). a crazy example is using 
    FIND_IN_SET(primary_index_column, "1,2,3")
using the primary key as first argument. with primary_index_column 
    IN (1,2,3)
MySQL is using the primary key as index, which is lightning fast - versus a string function which is very slow. the difference is sometimes 1000x.

e.g. this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
a1.usi as usishow,
m1.m1g1
FROM a1 LEFT JOIN p1 ON (a1.usi = p1.id)
```

`left join m1 on (m1.m1id = p1.emxid)
WHERE a1.umi=99999
AND p1.adi = 0 AND
p1.id IN (13700325,13700273,13692054,13691440,13692237,13691503,13691512,13691621,13691632,13691653,13691659,13691682,13691702,13691705,13691720,13691723,13691728,13691763,13691782,13691786,13691815,13691818,13691826,13691828,13691830,13691906,13691831,13691843,13691846,13691848,13691849,13691860,13691873,13691881,13691893,13691945,13691939,13691942,13691977,13692043,13691995,13691996,13692004,13692006,13692011,13692012,13692033,13692090,13692042,13692055,13692062,13692225,13692072,13692089,13692111,13692122,13692142,13692156,13692167,13692170,13692173,13692176,13692178,13692183,13692187,13692193,13692202,13692208,13692217,13692216,13692236,13692238,13692239,13692260,13692274,13692275,13692276,13692280,13692285,13692289,13692291,13692293,13692299,13692305,13692313,13692338,13692348,13692355,13692356,13692365,13692370,13692372,13692376,13692696,13692707,13692701,13692708,13692715,13692727,13692734,13692733,13692735,13692758,13692761,13692762,13692781,13692851,13692854,13694572,13697874,13697878,13697885,13697891,13697897,13697898,13697903,13697904,13697912,13697914,13699899,13697949,13697971,13697976,13698138,13698775,13699851,13699854,13699858,13699859,13699880,13699905,13699908,13699909,13699918,13699932,13699936,13699950,13699959,13699971,13700298,13700162,13700163,13700174,13700177,13700195,13700201,13700238,13700248,13700267,13700276,13700303,13700393,13700399,13700410)
ORDER BY usishow`

(containing the three tables a1, m1 and p1. p1.id is the primary index of p1.)
imagine using
    `FIND_IN_SET(p1.id, 13700325,13700273,...) > 0`
using no index, results in 14 sec (!) execution time.
versus

```
p1.id IN (13700325,13700273,...)
```

using primary index of p1, results in 0.02 sec (!) execution time.

so, test and 
`EXPLAIN (EXPLAIN SELECT ....)`
all queries using 
    `FIND_IN_SET` 
with columns that contain single values! It's worth the efford comparing with `IN (...)` - in most of the cases, you save a lot of time, memory (mayby disk reads) and cpu power!

Answer (score -1):

According to my understanding,

```
select * from table where find_in_set(x, 'a,b')
```

Would work faster because it searches a value against a list of values and skips the search as soon as it finds a match. But `OR` works for all the values in the column.

Correct me if i am wrong.